# mysql query with sum throgh 2 tables

Tags: mysql, join

I need get all (`distinta_base`.`qta`*`raggruppamento`.`qta_finale`) and `distinta_base`.`id_articolo` for every `raggruppamento`.`id_articolo` contained in the table `raggruppamento`.

for explanation I report my tables, my query and my result:

table: `raggruppamento`

[image]

with this records:
[image]

and the table `distinta_base`: 
[image][image]

my query:

```
SELECT a2.codice AS articolo_codice_db, a2.descrizione AS articolo_db_descrizione, a2.qta_min, a2.qta_max, a2.distinta_base, adb.id_articolo_db AS id_articolo_db, SUM(rp.qta_finale * adb.qta) AS qta_fabb 
FROM raggruppamento AS rp 
JOIN distinta_base AS adb ON adb.id_articolo = rp.id_articolo 
JOIN articolo AS a2 ON a2.id = adb.id_articolo_db
WHERE rp.id_raggruppamento_testa = 65 
GROUP BY id_articolo_db
```

and my wrong result:

[image]

`id_articolo_db -> 2059` 's qta should be:  5 + (50 * 2) = 105

[image]

Comment: Are there only ever 2 ids for every id_raggruppamento_testa? Note you are more likely to get a swift response if you replace the images with text.

Comment: no, could be more than 2

Comment: Can you expand your example to illustrate how raggruppamento would look if there were more than 2 and explain the logic for picking 5417 from distinta_base.

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed that you wish to sum the qta_finale values where the id for a specific testa is less than the max(id) for that testa and that last id contains the id_articlo to fulfil the join requirement to distinta_base.

```
drop table if exists raggruppamento;
create table raggruppamento (id int,testa int,articlo int,finale int);
insert into raggruppamento values
(30,45,918,2000),(31,45,918,2000),
(63,61,2059,5),(74,69,2056,8),(75,69,1366,9),
(76,65,2056,50),(77,65,2056,20),(78,65,2059,5);

drop table if exists distinta_base;
create table distinta_base(id int,id_articlo int,id_articlo_db int, qta int);
insert into distinta_base values
(5394,2056,2055,1),(5395,2056,2054,2),(5417,2056,2059,2),
(5398,2059,2060,1),(5399,2059,2061,2),(5406,2059,2062,2);

select r.*,r2.*,d.*,
        r2.finale + (r.finale1 * d.qta) fbb
from
(
select r1.testa test1,max(r1.articlo) articlo1, sum(r1.finale) finale1
from    raggruppamento r1
where r1.id <> (select max(r2.id) from raggruppamento r2 where r2.testa = r1.testa)
group   by r1.testa
) r
join raggruppamento r2 on r2.testa = r.test1 and r2.id = (select max(r2.id) from raggruppamento r2 where r2.testa = r.test1)
join distinta_base d on d.id_articlo = r.articlo1 and d.id_articlo_db = r2.articlo

+-------+----------+---------+------+-------+---------+--------+------+------------+---------------+------+------+
| test1 | articlo1 | finale1 | id   | testa | articlo | finale | id   | id_articlo | id_articlo_db | qta  | fbb  |
+-------+----------+---------+------+-------+---------+--------+------+------------+---------------+------+------+
|    65 |     2056 |      70 |   78 |    65 |    2059 |      5 | 5417 |       2056 |          2059 |    2 |  145 |
+-------+----------+---------+------+-------+---------+--------+------+------------+---------------+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```